# How to cache response with Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to develop restful API using Jersey.I have GET API's for a particular get operation my GET is taking same time from the same client.
Is it possible to cache  response? Any pointers is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use CacheControl, eTag - follow below example code

```
// In your jersey method
    final EntityTag eTag = new EntityTag(resource.getId() + "_" +
     resource.getLastModified().getTime());
    final CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl();
    cacheControl.setMaxAge(-1);

    ResponseBuilder builder = request.evaluatePreconditions(
         resource.getLastModified(), eTag);

    // the resoruce's information was modified, return it
    if (builder == null) {
         builder = Response.ok(resource);
    }

    // the resource's information was not modified, return a 304

    return builder.cacheControl(cacheControl).lastModified(
         resource.getLastModified()).tag(eTag).build();
```

Replace `resource` with your Resource instance.

Comment: Would u mind explaining why u disable Cache-Control (no-cache)?
Its like telling: sry no caching possible but look here I have a useless Etag and Last-Modified headers.

Comment: it is to say, its cached forever but server can say whether resource is modified based on e-tag , hence client/browser can use it from cache

Answer (score 8):

Summary of solutions:

1. [Request](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Request.html) as method parameter

   Interface:

   ```
    @Path("myentity")
    public interface MyEntityResource

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getMyEntity(@Context final Request request);
    }
   ```

   Implementation:

   ```
    public class MyEntityResourceImpl implements MyEntityResource

        @Override
        public Response getMyEntity(final Request request) {

            final MyEntity myEntity = ... // load entity
            final String eTagValue = ... // calclutate value of ETag

            final EntityTag eTag = new EntityTag(eTagValue);

            ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = request.evaluatePreconditions(eTag);

            if (responseBuilder == null) {
                return Response.ok(user).tag(eTag).build();
            }

            return responseBuilder.build();
        }
    }
   ```

   Disadvantages:

   - implementation detail `Request`is exposed
   - return type `Reponse` is generic
   - missing grammar of return type in WADL
   - [client proxy](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-Proxy-basedAPI) with unnecessary parameter `Request`
2. [Request](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Request.html) as instance variable

   Interface:

   ```
    @Path("myentity")
    public interface MyEntityResource

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getMyEntity();
    }
   ```

   Implementation:

   ```
    public class MyEntityResourceImpl implements MyEntityResource

        @Context
        private Request request

        @Override
        public Response getMyEntity() {

            final MyEntity myEntity = ... // load entity
            final String eTagValue = ... // calclutate value of ETag

            final EntityTag eTag = new EntityTag(eTagValue);

            ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = request.evaluatePreconditions(eTag);

            if (responseBuilder == null) {
                return Response.ok(user).tag(eTag).build();
            }

            return responseBuilder.build();
        }
    }
   ```

   Disadvantages:

   - return type `Reponse` is generic
   - missing grammar of return type in WADL
   - dependency injection with `@Context` is complicated, see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240443/combining-context-and-rolesallowed-in-a-jax-rs-resource)
3. [ShallowEtagHeaderFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.html) as web filter

   web.xml:

   ```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   ```

   Interface:

   ```
    @Path("myentity")
    public interface MyEntityResource

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public MyEntity getMyEntity();
    }
   ```

   Implementation:

   ```
    public class MyEntityResourceImpl implements MyEntityResource

        @Override
        public MyEntity getMyEntity() {

            final MyEntity myEntity = ... // load entity
            return myEntity;
        }
    }
   ```

   Disadvantages:

   - bad server performance, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.html)
   - works only on uncommitted response
   - no support of [weak ETag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3)
4. Custom [WriterInterceptor](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptor.html) as [JAX-RS Interceptor](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9806)

   Interceptor:

   ```
    public class CustomInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

        @Context
        private Request request;

        @Override
        public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

            OutputStream old = context.getOutputStream();

            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try {

                context.setOutputStream(buffer);
                context.proceed();

                byte[] entity = buffer.toByteArray();

                String etag = ... // calclutate value of ETag
                context.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.ETAG, etag);

                ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = request.evaluatePreconditions(eTag);

                if (responseBuilder == null) {
                     throw new WebApplicationException(responseBuilder.status(Response.Status.NOT_MODIFIED).header(HttpHeaders.ETAG, etag).build());
                }

                old.write(entity);

            } finally {
                context.setOutputStream(old);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   See also: [ServerCacheInterceptor](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-cache/resteasy-cache-core/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/cache/server/ServerCacheInterceptor.java) (Resteasy)

   Interface:

   ```
    @Path("myentity")
    public interface MyEntityResource

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public MyEntity getMyEntity();
    }
   ```

   Implementation:

   ```
    public class MyEntityResourceImpl implements MyEntityResource

        @Override
        public MyEntity getMyEntity() {

            final MyEntity myEntity = ... // load entity
            return myEntity;
        }
    }
   ```

   Disadvantages:

   - no predefined interceptor for Jersey available
   - bad server performance
   - no support of [weak ETag](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3)
   - ugly workaround with `WebApplicationException`

Answer (score 3):

You could use any caching mechanism applicable for standard java together with Jersey, like [Ehcache](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/).

You only have to pay attention to verify that your data in the backend hasn't changed.

Here is simple example with `Ehcache`:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public List<Data> getData(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    Element element = CacheManager.getInstance().getCache("test").get(id);
    if(element == null) {
        Data value = fetchElementFromBackend(id);
        CacheManager.getInstance().getCache("test").put(new Element(id, value));
        return value;
    }

    return element.getObjectValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've been solving a similar (if not the same) problem. As a side result of it the following library emerged:
https://github.com/AndreyLebedenko/dropwizard-caching-filter

The way it can be used is like below:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/cached")
@ResponseCachedByFilter(10000)
public Object getCached() {
    return dao.get();
}
```

Hope it helps.