# Combining @Context and @RolesAllowed in a JAX-RS resource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jax-rs, cxf

Is it possible to use [Context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html) annotation and [RolesAllowed](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) annotation in a JAX-RS resource with Apache CXF 2.4.6 and Spring Security 3.2.8?

My CXF configuration:

```xml
<jaxrs:server address="/example">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="myResourceImpl"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>
```

My Java source code:

```java
@Path("/myresource")
public interface MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    String get();
}

@Named
public class MyResourceImpl implements MyResource {

    @Context
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Override
    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_user")
    public String get() {
        return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```

After starting the server, I get the following exception:

```text
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext field MyResourceImpl.securityContext to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy473
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils$1.run(InjectionUtils.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.injectFieldValue(InjectionUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.injectContextProxiesAndApplication(InjectionUtils.java:912)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.injectContexts(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:354)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.updateClassResourceProviders(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:380)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:145)
    ... 59 more
```

If I remove one of the annotations, it works fine.

The problem seems to be that Spring creates a [proxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies) and Apache CXF cannot inject that proxy with the [SecurityContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html).

I have to use Spring Security and cannot use [container-based security](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxe.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use @RolesAllowed on RESTful Resources implemented on Apache CXF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433315/can-i-use-rolesallowed-on-restful-resources-implemented-on-apache-cxf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found four work-arounds:

1. Extended Interface

   ```
    @Path("/myresource")
    public interface MyResource {

        @Context 
        public void setSecurityContext(Security securityContext); 

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
        String get();
    }

    @Named
    public class MyResourceImpl implements MyResource {

        private SecurityContext securityContext;

        @Override
        public void setSecurityContext(Security securityContext) { 
            this.securityContext = securityContext
        }

        @Override
        @RolesAllowed("ROLE_user")
        public String get() {
            return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        }
    }
   ```

   But this solution is not perfect, because my [client](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAXRSClientAPI-Proxy-basedAPI) should not see implementation details.
2. [Dedicated interface](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/IllegalArgumentException-for-UriInfo-context-injection-td5718839.html)

   If I add a second interface with a public setter for `SecurityContext`, Apache CXF could inject the [JDK proxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies) with `SecurityContext`.

   ```
    public interface ContextAware { 

        @Context 
        public void setSecurityContext(Security securityContext); 
    } 

    @Path("/myresource")
    public interface MyResource {

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
        String get();
    }

    @Named
    public class MyResourceImpl implements MyResource, ContextAware  {

        private SecurityContext securityContext;

        @Override
        public void setSecurityContext(Security securityContext) { 
            this.securityContext = securityContext
        }

        @Override
        @RolesAllowed("ROLE_user")
        public String get() {
            return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        }
    }
   ```
3. [CGLIB proxy without interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies)

   If I remove the interface Spring uses a CGLIB proxy.

   ```
    @Named
    @Path("/myresource")
    public class MyResourceImpl {

        @Context
        private SecurityContext securityContext;

        @RolesAllowed("ROLE_superadmin")
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
        public String get() {
            return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        }
    }
   ```

   But this solution is not good, because my [client](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-Proxy-basedAPI) should not see implementation details. And my client should not need implementation dependencies.
4. [CGLIB proxy with interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying)

   ```
    @Path("/myresource")
    public interface MyResource {

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
        String get();
    }

    @Named
    public class MyResourceImpl implements MyResource {

        @Context
        private SecurityContext securityContext;

        @Override
        @RolesAllowed("ROLE_user")
        public String get() {
            return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I took a slight variation on the solution from @dur. Instead of having the `@Context` as a field, I passed it as a parameter to my method that needed it (I was using `SecurityContext`):

```java
@Path("/myresource")
public interface MyResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    String get(@Context SecurityContext securityContext);
}

@Named
public class MyResourceImpl implements MyResource {
    @Override
    @RolesAllowed("ROLE_user")
    public String get(SecurityContext securityContext) {
        return securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
}
```